# Why does `decimal.Decimal` still give rounding errors?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding-error

I am using `decimal.Decimal` instead of `float` explicitly to avoid rounding errors, but am still getting them:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('9') * (Decimal('10') / Decimal('9'))
Decimal('9.999999999999999999999999999')
>>> Decimal('9') * (Decimal('10') / Decimal('9')) == Decimal('10')
False
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: `10/9` can't be represented exactly in decimal, it's a repeating decimal `1.11111...`

Comment: What you need for this is the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module.

Comment: What leads you to expect that using `Decimal` avoids rounding errors?